# Insert record into database using javascript, mysql, and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have the following js function, which makes an ajax request, but it is not doing it for some reason. I checked alerting url and it displays it as it supposed to be, so all variables are declared.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "ajax_js/q_ajax.php?q="+ques+
                            "&ans="+ans+
                            "&a="+inp[0].value+
                            "&b="+inp[2].value+
                            "&c="+inp[4].value+
                            "&d="+inp[6].value+
                            "&cor="+checked+
                            "&def="+input+
                            "&q_n="+q_name+
                            "&c_id="+c_id;
request.onreadystatechange=function (){
    if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}
```

Here is the code from php file.

```
<?php
require("db_conx.php");
$q = $_GET['q'];
$ans = $_GET['ans'];
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
$c = $_GET['c'];
$d = $_GET['d'];
$cor = $_GET['cor'];
$def = $_GET['def'];
$q_n = $_GET['q_n'];
$c_id = $_GET['c_id'];


$q = mysqli_escape_string($con, $q);
$ans = mysqli_escape_string($con, $ans);
$a = mysqli_escape_string($con, $a);
$b = mysqli_escape_string($con, $b);
$c = mysqli_escape_string($con, $c);
$d = mysqli_escape_string($con, $d);
$cor = mysqli_escape_string($con, $cor);
$def = mysqli_escape_string($con, $def);
$q_n = mysqli_escape_string($con, $q_n);
$c_id = mysqli_escape_string($con, $c_id);


/* Modify id for the system  */
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO course_quiz (course_id, quiz_name, question, des_answer, ChoiceA,
                                                      ChoiceB, ChoiceC, ChoiceD, correct, def)
                            VALUES ('$c_id', '$q_n', '$q', '$ans', '$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$cor', '$def')");
echo('Question has been saved');
/* header('Location: ../instr_home.php'); */
```

I also have an another ajax call(works perfect) in the same page, which I think the reason of the problem. Variables for XMLHttpRequest are named different as well.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the console ? did you find any javascript errors ?

Comment: @Nandan yes, I checked and console does not show any errors.

Comment: Are you getting any response ??   Simply echo (only echo) a message in php file and check whether you get response or not.

Comment: I am not getting any response. It looks like it is not running the php part. I checked the url to the files and they are correct.

Comment: are you running on localhost ? I think you are trying to run HTML page which contains ajax call directly.

Comment: I am running on localhost, but it is php page.

Comment: Ok, I have written 1 answer, check whether it works.

Comment: Load the PHP page with the GET parameters, works? Errors?

Comment: @user3783243 I tried that before asking the question, that did not help

Comment: What happened, empty page? Do you have error reporting on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced ajax, by Jquery ajax,

Make sure all the URL variables are initialized before passing through url.

Change the $_GET method to $_POST in your PHP file.

Just Copy-Paste the solution.

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
  function ajax()
  {

  var urlString ="q="+ques+"&ans="+ans+"&a="+inp[0].value+"&b="+inp[2].value+"&c="+inp[4].value+"&d="+inp[6].value+"&cor="+checked+"&def="+input+"&q_n="+q_name+"&c_id="+c_id;

  $.ajax
  ({
  url: "ajax_js/q_ajax.php",
  type : "POST",
  cache : false,
  data : urlString,
  success: function(response)
  {
  alert(response);
  }
  });


  }

  </script>
```

In your PHP file,

```
 <?php
 require("db_conx.php");
 $q = $_POST['q'];
 $ans = $_POST['ans'];
 $a = $_POST['a'];
 $b = $_POST['b'];
 $c = $_POST['c'];
 $d = $_POST['d'];
 $cor = $_POST['cor'];
 $def = $_POST['def'];
 $q_n = $_POST['q_n'];
 $c_id = $_POST['c_id'];


 $q = mysqli_escape_string($con, $q);
 $ans = mysqli_escape_string($con, $ans);
 $a = mysqli_escape_string($con, $a);
 $b = mysqli_escape_string($con, $b);
 $c = mysqli_escape_string($con, $c);
 $d = mysqli_escape_string($con, $d);
 $cor = mysqli_escape_string($con, $cor);
 $def = mysqli_escape_string($con, $def);
 $q_n = mysqli_escape_string($con, $q_n);
 $c_id = mysqli_escape_string($con, $c_id);


 /* Modify id for the system  */
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO course_quiz (course_id, quiz_name, question, des_answer, ChoiceA,
                                                       ChoiceB, ChoiceC, ChoiceD, correct, def)
                             VALUES ('$c_id', '$q_n', '$q', '$ans', '$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$cor', '$def')");
 echo('Question has been saved');
 /* header('Location: ../instr_home.php'); */
 ?>
```

Comment: thank you it helped. But it is weird to me that jquery works and javascript does not

Comment: Please upvote if it worked,  First just try to run simple ajax (javascript) and check whether you get response or not, if you get response, please change from "get" to "POST" in both the files,  even that must work.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but dont have enough reputation in here. I am new here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code with this and you find your error

```js
request.onreadystatechange=function (){
    //if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
        alert(request.responseText);
    //}
}
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.send();
```